# EventListener on listbox no longer works after item dropped [All javascript functionality ceases after a successful drop]

Tags: javascript, c#, events, drag-and-drop, listbox

This is a proof of concept project in an attempt to use javascript to enable an event listener on a listbox and execute javascript drag and drop to the same listbox.

When executing the code, if I click on the listbox first, the javascript function tied to the event listener (pickupSticks) executes as is demonstrated by a couple of alert statements.

However, if I place some text in the first textbox and drag and drop it into the first listbox, my click event no longer fires.  The same thing happens if I use the actual button to move the data once.

The reason my javascript include is where it is, is that it seems as if the objects must be created before the addEventListener can find the listbox or an error is returned (not able to find object).

What confuses me is the apparent deactivation of the eventListener AND my javascript code after a successful drop.

DEFAULT.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test D&D and Click Event on listbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" draggable ="true"  ondragstart = "drag(event)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" draggable="true" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"  runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
         <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
         </div>
         </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </form>
   <script src = "dragndrop.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Default.aspx.js looks like this:

```
using System;
//project compiles and executes without these libraries.
//using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Web;
//using System.Web.UI;
//using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Apples");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Bananas");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Oranges");
            TextBox2.Focus();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text);
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
        }
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Focus();
    }
    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //this fires only when adding an element to the listbox    
    TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
    }
}
```

dragNdrop.js:

```
//dragNdrop.js

//add event listeners
var mouseClick = document.getElementById("ListBox1");
mouseClick.addEventListener("click", pickupSticks, false);
var mouseClick = document.getElementById("ListBox2");
mouseClick.addEventListener("click", pickupSticks, false);

//base functions
function drag(ev) {
           ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
       }

function drop(ev) {
    document.getElementById("Button1").click();
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
    //get and store the target listbox id
    ev.preventDefault();
    var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    target = elementMouseIsOver.id;
    document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = target;
}

//special functions
function pickupSticks()
{
    alert("PickupSticks");
    var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
        elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    target = elementMouseIsOver.id;
    document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = target;
    alert(document.getElementById(target).selectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory as to what may be happening.

I notice your .net controls are inside an update panel. Update panels are a way of abstracting away some ajax behavior.

So, on the first attempt, everything works. But, I see that ListBox1 has a server side event handler in you c# code. That tells me it may be posting back to the server. If it does, that means that after the postback, the contents of your update panel are re-created.

So, in your javascript, the listbox you initially bound to is gone. There's a new one there that looks just like it in every way, but it isn't the *same one*.

For this instance, I'd recommend you go all server-side, all client-side, or call a function to rebind your event handlers each time the update panel is drawn.

Comment: I will give this a try.  I was trapped into using Ajax to solve one problem, but it looks like I created a monster.

Comment: Ajax in itself isn't terrible at all. It's just a matter of knowing how everything plays together. Things can get weird when you mix client and server side functionality unless you know exactly where the boundaries are.

Comment: I removed the ajax controls and added one line of code to the button.  The line of code:  ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; and everything works.  KUDOS.